# GitLab Docker ASP.NET ARG

Tags: asp.net, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm developing a small test aplication and i wanted to automate the publish process, but i cant find a solution to how to pass docker arguments into the dockerfile.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

ARG CONFIGURATION=Release

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["NAVSzamlazoAPI/NAVSzamlazoAPI.csproj", "NAVSzamlazoAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "NAVSzamlazoAPI/NAVSzamlazoAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/NAVSzamlazoAPI"
RUN dotnet build "NAVSzamlazoAPI.csproj" -c $CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "NAVSzamlazoAPI.csproj" -c $CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "NAVSzamlazoAPI.dll"]
```

And here is the gitlab ci

```
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  IMAGE_NAME: ******
  IMAGE_TAG: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

stages:
  - build
  - push
  - update

build_image:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build --build-arg COMMIT_SHA=$CI_COMMIT_SHA --build-arg CONFIGURATION=Release -t $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
  only:
    - release

push_image:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: push
  script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
  only:
    - release
  when: on_success

apply_migrations:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
  stage: update
  script:
    - dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 8.0.1
    - export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
    - cd csomag_porta.DAL
    - dotnet ef database update --configuration Release
  only:
    - release
  when: on_success

update_portainer_service:
  image: ruby:2.7-alpine
  stage: update
  script:
    - apk --no-cache add curl  # Install curl if not present in image
    - >
     curl -k --location --request POST '****'
  only:
    - release
  when: on_success

build_image_beta:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build --build-arg COMMIT_SHA=$CI_COMMIT_SHA --build-arg CONFIGURATION=Debug -t $IMAGE_NAME:beta-$IMAGE_TAG .
  only:
    - beta

push_image_beta:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: push
  script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker push $IMAGE_NAME:beta-$IMAGE_TAG
  only:
    - beta
  when: on_success

apply_migrations_beta:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
  stage: update
  script:
    - dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 8.0.1
    - export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
    - cd csomag_porta.DAL
    - dotnet ef database update --configuration Beta
  only:
    - beta
  when: on_success

update_portainer_service_beta:
  image: ruby:2.7-alpine
  stage: update
  script:
    - apk --no-cache add curl  # Install curl if not present in image
    - >
     curl -k --location --request POST '********'
  only:
    - beta
  when: on_success
```

And the error i get:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.9.1 (d540b510)
  on devserver DsS_dm-X, system ID: s_e14194b71241
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:03
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Pulling docker image docker:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:8e852d8fa68066ef1d10d83651c63d411b0f916b4bd2822b9d96865d80da2148 for docker:latest with digest docker@sha256:91c7180444442d2596355a2859317d86c73025c63c67bceca3e16cd09a08e649 ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-dssdm-x-project-27-concurrent-0 via devserver...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/skyframeskft/nav-szamlazo-api/.git/
Checking out e2109c0c as detached HEAD (ref is beta)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:03
Using docker image sha256:8e852d8fa68066ef1d10d83651c63d411b0f916b4bd2822b9d96865d80da2148 for docker:latest with digest docker@sha256:91c7180444442d2596355a2859317d86c73025c63c67bceca3e16cd09a08e649 ...
$ docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
Login Succeeded
$ docker build --build-arg COMMIT_SHA=$CI_COMMIT_SHA --build-arg CONFIGURATION=Debug -t $IMAGE_NAME:beta-$IMAGE_TAG .
#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver
#1 [internal] load .dockerignore
#1 transferring context: 358B done
#1 DONE 0.0s
#2 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#2 transferring dockerfile: 850B done
#2 DONE 0.0s
#3 [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
#3 DONE 0.0s
#4 [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
#4 DONE 0.2s
#5 [base 1/2] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0@sha256:3ff67792728179308c4bf06799d8b45d155c60fddc347acf69465a496d9a20b8
#5 DONE 0.0s
#6 [build 1/7] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
#6 DONE 0.0s
#7 [internal] load build context
#7 transferring context: 189.83kB 0.0s done
#7 DONE 0.0s
#8 [build 4/7] RUN dotnet restore "NAVSzamlazoAPI/NAVSzamlazoAPI.csproj"
#8 CACHED
#9 [build 5/7] COPY . .
#9 CACHED
#10 [build 2/7] WORKDIR /src
#10 CACHED
#11 [build 3/7] COPY [NAVSzamlazoAPI/NAVSzamlazoAPI.csproj, NAVSzamlazoAPI/]
#11 CACHED
#12 [build 6/7] WORKDIR /src/NAVSzamlazoAPI
#12 CACHED
#13 [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build "NAVSzamlazoAPI.csproj" -c $CONFIGURATION -o /app/build
#13 1.056 MSBuild version 17.8.3+195e7f5a3 for .NET
#13 1.059 MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
#13 1.059     Full command line: '/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.101/MSBuild.dll -maxcpucount -verbosity:m -restore -consoleloggerparameters:Summary -property:Configuration=-o NAVSzamlazoAPI.csproj /app/build -distributedlogger:Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.MSBuild.MSBuildLogger,/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.101/dotnet.dll*Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.MSBuild.MSBuildForwardingLogger,/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.101/dotnet.dll'
#13 1.059   Switches appended by response files:
#13 1.059 Switch: /app/build
#13 1.059 
#13 1.059 For switch syntax, type "MSBuild -help"
#13 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet build \"NAVSzamlazoAPI.csproj\" -c $CONFIGURATION -o /app/build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [build 7/7] RUN dotnet build "NAVSzamlazoAPI.csproj" -c $CONFIGURATION -o /app/build:
1.056 MSBuild version 17.8.3+195e7f5a3 for .NET
1.059 MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
1.059     Full command line: '/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.101/MSBuild.dll -maxcpucount -verbosity:m -restore -consoleloggerparameters:Summary -property:Configuration=-o NAVSzamlazoAPI.csproj /app/build -distributedlogger:Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.MSBuild.MSBuildLogger,/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.101/dotnet.dll*Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.MSBuild.MSBuildForwardingLogger,/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.101/dotnet.dll'
1.059   Switches appended by response files:
1.059 Switch: /app/build
1.059 
1.059 For switch syntax, type "MSBuild -help"
------
WARNING: current commit information was not captured by the build: git was not found in the system: exec: "git": executable file not found in $PATH
Dockerfile:16
--------------------
  14 |     COPY . .
  15 |     WORKDIR "/src/NAVSzamlazoAPI"
  16 | >>> RUN dotnet build "NAVSzamlazoAPI.csproj" -c $CONFIGURATION -o /app/build
  17 |     
  18 |     FROM build AS publish
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet build \"NAVSzamlazoAPI.csproj\" -c $CONFIGURATION -o /app/build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Any idea how can i fix this?

The project should create a "Debug" Docker Image